# set style value using Javascript variable not work

Tags: javascript, css

Using javascript variable for setting CSS style values not work, this is my javascript code:

```
imageH.src = "image.jpg";
imageH.onload = function() {
    var valueH = (this.height/this.width)*100;
  }

var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div.style.paddingTop = valueH + '%';
```

this not work, but if i use the value betwen "" :

```
div.style.paddingTop = "60%";
```

it work.

Thanks!!

Comment: `valueH` is only defined inside the `onload` function. Declare it outside instead.

Comment: of course!!, maybe i need sleep more, thanks

Comment: Also note that the function runs *after* your `div1` stuff (which completely escaped me previously)

Answer (score 0):

Move `valueH` outside of function:

```
imageH.src = "image.jpg";

var valueH;

imageH.onload = function() {
    valueH = (this.height/this.width)*100;
  }

var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div.style.paddingTop = valueH + '%';
```